# How to validate $_FILES using Respect Validation library

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I'm using [Respect Validation](http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/image.html) to attempt to validate a file upload. The problem I'm having is the validation always fails, even though the correct image has been uploaded.

Here's my code:

```
public function updateProfilePicture(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {

    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();

    if(empty($files['image'])) {
        throw new AppException('Invalid image');
    }

    // Validate image
    $validator = v::key('image', v::image());

    try {
        $validator->assert($files);
        // $validator->assert($_FILES);
    } catch(NestedValidationException $e) {
        throw new AppException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "data": null,
  "message": "All of the required rules must pass for { \"image\": { \"name\": \"twitter.png\", \"type\": \"image/png\", \"tmp_name\": \"/private/var/folders/ry/kgy3g6v96s71jg3htn6r5rt80000gn/T/php7x3P6w\", \"error\": 0, \"size\": 210955 } }"
}
```

As suggested in the comments I tried using `$validator->assert($files['image']);`. This didn't work and yields the following error:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "data": null,
  "message": "All of the required rules must pass for `[object] (Slim\\Http\\UploadedFile: { \"file\": \"/private/var/folders/ry/kgy3g6v96s71jg3htn6r5rt80000gn/T/phppJn1Uw\" })`"
}
```

The `$files` variable contains:

```
array(1) {
  ["image"]=>
  object(Slim\Http\UploadedFile)#120 (8) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(66) "/private/var/folders/ry/kgy3g6v96s71jg3htn6r5rt80000gn/T/php8sPpkD"
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(11) "twitter.png"
    ["type":protected]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["size":protected]=>
    int(210955)
    ["error":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["sapi":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["stream":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["moved":protected]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

And `$_FILES` contains:

```
array(1) {
  ["image"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "twitter.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(66) "/private/var/folders/ry/kgy3g6v96s71jg3htn6r5rt80000gn/T/phpm0Gv35"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(210955)
  }
}
```

As suggested in the comment I've tried `$validator->assert($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` and get the following error:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "data": null,
  "message": "All of the required rules must pass for \"/private/var/folders/ry/kgy3g6v96s71jg3htn6r5rt80000gn/T/php8E5apg\""
}
```

I've tried to Google to see how others are doing it but was unable to find anything useful.

Comment: Have you tried this? `$validator->assert($files['image']);`

Comment: @LucasdeOliveira tried that to no avail. I've updated my answer to show the error.

Comment: What does this variable `$files` return? If it is the same that `$_FILES` return, you can try to do this: `$validator->assert($files['image']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: @deoliveiralucas tried that too. I've updated the question.

Comment: What does this return `var_dump((new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE))->file($files['image']));`?

Comment: @deoliveiralucas I tried `var_dump((new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE))->file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));` and the result is `string(9) "image/png"`

Comment: LOL and does this return `false`? `var_dump(v::image()->validate($_FILES['image']['tmp_name‌​']));`

Comment: @deoliveiralucas put that as an answer. That works.

Comment: \o/ this image validator just validade the mimetype..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
var_dump(v::image()->validate($_FILES['image']['tmp_name‌​']‌​));
```